# Instruments crashed on startup in Appium when i use a build from developer profile

Tags: appium, ui-automation, web-inspector, appium-ios

I'm trying to open inspector in appium with a build from developer profile but i inspector and instruments crashed on startup.

When i create a new project and generate the .app file it works fine.
I can record my test cases with appium.

Comment: what version of android you are using??

Comment: 5.0.1 in sumsung galaxy s4, but i'm talking about ios not android here. 
.app not .apk

Comment: Three things : 1. Are you able to access the instruments in ways other than appium script? 2. Also please make sure you have `Use Native Instruments Library` checked under `Advance settings` for IOS platform in Appium's UI. 3. `Enable UI Automation` setting in setting--developer

Comment: Ok thanks it must be 2 option, but i didn't well understand what i mean be access to the instrument in ways other than scripts? You mean from console of appium or from itunes?